# How to get the list of work items linked to a build pipeline via the REST API in Azure

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I'd like to get the list of work items (id) that are linked to a current build pipeline from some PowerShell script using the Azure Rest API, how can I do that?

Azure Devops Server 2019

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20build%20work%20items%20refs?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to get the list of work items linked to a build pipeline via the REST API in Azure

There is a out of box API to get the list of work items linked to a build pipeline:

[Builds - Get Build Work Items Refs:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20build%20work%20items%20refs?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0):

```
GET https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/workitems?api-version=5.0
```

The powershell script:

```
$url = "http://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/2945/workitems?api-version=5.0"
$LinkedworkItems= Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{   
 Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
} -Method Get

Write-Host "Linked work items= $($LinkedworkItems| ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
```

Note: Need go to the Agent Phase and select Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token:

[image]

The result:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Cheers, I had a sightly wrong URI, missing a `/build/`